# Rubberized stylus, not moving smooth on iPad glass, any tricks?

Tags: ipad, stylus

I have a Targus stylus for my iPad, with a rubber tip.

This tip, however, does not move smoothly over the glass on the iPad, but seems to have too high friction. It didn't have this when I bought it, and I also have a different stylus that is much smaller, also with a rubber tip, that still moves smoothly over the glass.

The large one, however, gets "stuck" on the screen. Not like glue "stuck", just doesn't move as smoothly as I'd like.

What tricks can I use to get it back to how it was when I bought it? Has it accrued fat from my fingers or something like that I can wash off, or are there other things I can do? Has anyone experienced this and solved it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think most of these answers are pure speculation and the long term effects on your iPad's screen are at question.

I would suggest that you simply look to replace the stylus as it has evidently worn out. It may be that they are not very durable products, but I certainly wouldn't recommend trying to hack a solution over just buying a new stylus.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases using a lubricant like Silicon grease would help.

Just enough to lubricate, then wipe it off with tissue.

Silicon grease is transparent so you will not "see" the marks on the screen.

Better solution is to find a Silicon rubber tip.

Answer (score 2):

Lightly coat the rubber with a thin film superglue. Make sure the glue is smooth with no bubbles or ripples.  Let it dry. Clean your screen and voila smooth gliding stylus.

Comment: Wouldn't the residual solvent or the glue itself damage the oleophobic coating on the glass?

Comment: Actually my concern would be that superglue is quite hard and scratchy yes.

Answer (score 0):

This may be only a coincidence, but I felt that the stylus tip might have gotten dirty.  I rubbed it against a soft cloth, and it started working again. Can't guarantee it will work for everyone, but it only takes a few seconds to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary solution (1-2 hours): dip the nib in flour and rub the flour in. Tap it to knock off the visible flour.

Answer (score 0):

Thus far corn starch. But doesn't last. Believe it or not I've found my actual facial oils from my face have seems to work the best and last longer.

Answer (score 0):

Tape a small piece of scotch tape to the end and replace regularly

Answer (score -1):

Push the rubber tip in so you have a hard end, making you able to use it easily.

Comment: How do you mean to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Spray the rubber end with anti-perspirant.

Answer (score -1):

Working off the pr vinous post, i used a touch of deodorant (the stick kind) it's as good as new